# How to make scaladoc show default parameter values?

Tags: scala, default-value, scala-2.10, default-parameters, scaladoc

I have many methods like

```
def foo(..., ..., runFinalizer: Boolean = true)
         (implicit finalizer: Finalizer): Result = ...
```

But when I run scaladoc (using sbt), it doesn't document that `runFinalizer` has the default value. This is quite problematic, because users will set the parameter to `false` very rarely, and the generated documentation doesn't show it can be omitted.

So far, I have two solutions, neither one completely satisfactory:

1. Document the fact that `runFinalizer` can be omitted inside its `@param` block. It helps, but results in duplicating such a sentence in many places in the documentation, and it's possible for users to overlook it.
2. Create two variants of the method, one with `runFinalizers` (with no default value) and one without. But this would unnecessarily double the number of methods and clutter both code and the documentation.

Comment: Not sure why the defaults aren't showing up in the Scaladoc. It's definitely possible - take a look at `http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0.5/#akka.testkit.TestKit`, the `receiveWhile` method. There is nothing special in the source code for that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely a bug, occurring only in some cases: [SI-4922 Omitted default argument values](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4922) . I upgraded to Scala 2.10.1. and it's working fine.